# Set an alert to current tab from background script: alert is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a pomodoro extension. When the timer reaches certain times, it will alert the user. This is the context in my `background.js` file in which I'm trying to call `alert()`.

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  popupPort = port;
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    if (msg.cmd == "START_TIMER") {
      currentPomodoro = 1500;
      totalSessionTime = 0;
      buttonMode = "End";
      popupPort.postMessage({countdown: "00:25:00", totalTime: "00:00:00", mode: buttonMode})
      pomodoroInterval = setInterval(incrementTimer, 1000);
    }
  })
})
const incrementTimer = () => {
  currentPomodoro = currentPomodoro - 1;
  totalSessionTime = totalSessionTime + 1;
  var pts = 0;
  if (currentPomodoro % 5 == 0) pts = 10;
  chrome.storage.sync.get("points", (data) => {
    var total = data.points + pts
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"points": total});
    var countdownTimer = secToTimer(currentPomodoro);
    var sessionTimer = secToTimer(totalSessionTime);
    popupPort.postMessage({countdown: countdownTimer, totalTime: sessionTimer, points: total})
  })
  if (currentPomodoro == 1498) {
    popupPort.postMessage({alert: "break"})
    alert("Break soon");
  }
}
```

This results in `Uncaught ReferenceError: alert is not defined`. Calling it from my popup.js file also results in the same error. My only workaround is to instead do `chrome.windows.create` but that's less preferable.

Comment: 1. In a ManifestV3 service worker there's no `alert` per specification. 2. In the popup it exists so it must be a different problem e.g. a typo or you're looking at an old error. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.

Comment: The different issue, with that, which I forgot previously, is that my popup.js uses React to render to a popup.html. The issues are that 1) the message it receives from my background script is received multiple times so alerts are called dozens of times, and 2) it only alerts to the popup, so if the popup isn't open, it doesn't alert. I'm not sure how to get it to whichever tab is currently active.